# Where should i put a timer that call a method every 5 minutes

Tags: asp.net

Where should i put a timer that call a method every 5 minutes ?

i put it in MasterPage but call every time that i load a page that use this MasterPage but i want to call just every 5 minutes

i use this code in MasterPage

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="divNews" class="news" runat="server"></div>

            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="divTit">
                        <table style=" width:100%">
                            <tr style=" width:100%; text-align:right;">
                                <td style=" width:100%;"><!--Inbox-->
                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="lblMainMenu1" runat="server" ID="lblInbox" OnClick="inbox_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    <asp:Label Text="Inbox :" runat="server" CssClass="lblMainMenu2"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="timer" EventName="Tick" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            <asp:Timer Interval="1" ID="timer" OnTick="timer_Tick" runat="server"></asp:Timer>

        <div id="body" class="divBody">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentMain" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps start the timer in your `Application_OnStart`?  Or, run this code in an outside process.

Comment: I start the timer in PageLoad and in if (!IsPostBack)

Comment: "Every 5 minutes" for each user? Globally for the process? In a background thread? In a request-handling thread? Please, explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If you're trying to run *server side code* every five minutes, I don't think it makes sense to start a timer within the context of an HTTP request.  The thread that handled that request may or may not exist 5 minutes later.  Perhaps explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to check a method every 5 minutes for every user that login to website

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do this within a page. As you've seen, you can't really create a long-running scheduled task reliably in this way.

The best way to do this really depends on what, exactly, it is that you want to do.

If you're looking to update a page in-browser every five minutes, you can set a timer in JavaScript and perform an AJAX request to retrieve updated content. Alternatively - easier, but less clean - you could use the [HTTP-equiv meta attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp) to refresh the entire page every five minutes. However, as the link states, this breaks some accessibility rules. Also, if you have a form that the user is completing, whatever information they've entered will be lost when the page refreshes.

If you're trying to trigger some server-side task that's not user-specific, you can a few different routes:

1. Create a Windows service that runs on a server (probably your web server, but it could be anywhere). You can either put the code that you need to run every five minutes in the service directly, or use something like [WebClient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient) to request a page from your site which then performs whatever tasks you require.
2. Create a console app, PowerShell script, etc. that uses WebClient to retrieve the page, and add it to the [Windows task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) to have it run every few minutes. This has the advantage of not requiring you to create service, if that's something with which your not familiar or comfortable.
3. Rather than writing a script or console app, use a utility such as [wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm). Use the task scheduler mentioned above to run it every few minutes, specifying the desired URL as a command line parameter. This is probably the easiest, but gives up some of the flexibility offered by the other two options.

** Update **
If you just want to update some content within the page periodically as you've stated (checking for messages, etc.), there's [a very simple tutorial that doesn't require you to create any JavaScript here](http://pankajlalwani.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/refresh-content-in-updatepanel-using-asp-net-ajax-timer-control/).

For purposes of archive integrity, here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Update Panel and Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Timer runat="server" id="UpdateTimer" interval="5000"
          ontick="UpdateTimer_Tick" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer"
                  eventname="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbldatetime" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In the codebehind:

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
lbldatetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Comment: the method that i want to call it every 5 minutes check that current user have any email (this email is internal email and i read it from my database because this website has several users and users can send email)

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad in that case, AJAX is your best bet. See this link for a decent tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/364074/timercontrol-with-updatepanel-in-ajax-using-Asp-Net/

Comment: it works but a big problem : i add a label with Text="" in MasterPage that set it's Text in updateMethod(method that call with timer),now when i go to other pages that use this MasterPage because controls that exist in MasterPage recreate this label's text is "" until next time that timer call

Comment: You can't update server-side controls that way unless they're in an UpdatePanel or similar control that's re-rendered when the AJAX call is processed. You'll need to update the text from within your client-side script, or place the controls in an UpdatePanel and change the text in the panel's render event.

Comment: @Sajjjjjjad Added example to my answer.

Comment: I implemented update panel like this before in MasterPage but every time that i load a page that use this MasterPage recreate all controls then the label's text is "" until timer call

Comment: You have to set the initial control content, or it'll be blank until it's updated. Alternatively, call the timer immediately the first time (interval of ~0) and change it on the first render.

Comment: again my problem is : when i load other pages label's text is "" until next time that timer call,because controls that exist in MasterPage recreate every time that i load a page

Comment: The updatePanel should fix that. Only the panel should be re-rendered when the timer expires. Consider adding your code to your question.